# Cloning into 'edx-certificates-internal'... Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, github, openedx

i want to install openedx-certificates
using this link https://github.com/Stanford-Online/openedx-certificates

```
root@MCIT:~# git clone git@github.com:edx/edx-certificates-internal
Cloning into 'edx-certificates-internal'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
root@MCIT:~# ssh -T git@github.com
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: You do realise you are working as root (judging by the prompt) and not your normal user account, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setting up SSH Authentication for Github

Assuming that you want to do this as the root user, the second command you ran is the crux of the problem. You are trying to use SSH authentication to access the GitHub repository, however SSH authentication is not configured (or not configured at all for your GitHub account).

"[Adding a new SSH Key to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/)" is the official Github documentation for this and involves generating an SSH key pair and adding the public key to the appropriate place in your Github account (at the time of this writing, this is Settings -> SSH and GPG Keys -> Add new SSH key or, https://github.com/settings/keys).

To summarize the steps are :

1. [Generate an SSH key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#generating-a-new-ssh-key) (Notice that the instructions vary based on the Operating System)
2. Add the key to the locally running ssh-agent to save you from typing the passphrase over and over (of course, this is assuming that you used one to create the key in #1 above)
3. Finally adding the SSH key to Github as mentioned previously (https://github.com/settings/keys)

The details for all of this are well documented in the top most link. 
`ssh -T git@github.com` is the command to use to test your setup once you have followed the steps.

---

#### First time git setup

Also, if this is the first time you are using git, then '[First-Time Git Setup](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup)' is worth a read and at the bare minimum you should setup your identity by doing:

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```